# Equality in Python's list-comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have forgotten equalities in Python's list-comprehension

```
[str(a)+str(b)+str(c) for a in range(3) for b in range(3) for c in range(3)]
['000', '001', '002', '010', '011', '012', '020', '021', '022', '100', '101', '102', '110', '111', '112', '120', '121', '122', '200', '201', '202', '210', '211', '212', '220', '221', '222']
```

where I want to make restriction a!=b and b!=c. `for a!=b for b!=c` at the end did not work. So how to have equality constraint in the list-comprehension?

Comment: use `if` instead of `for`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
["{}{}{}".format(a,b,c) for a in range(3) for b in range(3) 
                                              for c in range(3) if a!=b and b!=c]
```

or better use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> ["{}{}{}".format(a,b,c)  for a, b, c in product(range(3), repeat=3)
                                                               if a!=b and b!=c]
['010', '012', '020', '021', '101', '102', '120', '121', '201', '202', '210', '212']
```

**Update :**

```
>>> from itertools import product, izip, tee
def check(lis):
    it1, it2 = tee(lis)
    next(it2)
    return all(x != y for x,y in izip(it1, it2))
... 

>>> n = 3
>>> [("{}"*n).format(*p)  for p in product(range(3), repeat=n) if check(p)]
['010', '012', '020', '021', '101', '102', '120', '121', '201', '202', '210', '212']
>>> n = 4
>>> [("{}"*n).format(*p)  for p in product(range(3), repeat=n) if check(p)]
['0101', '0102', '0120', '0121', '0201', '0202', '0210', '0212', '1010', '1012', '1020', '1021', '1201', '1202', '1210', '1212', '2010', '2012', '2020', '2021', '2101', '2102', '2120', '2121']
```

Comment: Can you scale this easily to $n$ amount of for -loops? So you have $n-1$ amount of equality constraints and $n$ amount of for -loops with $n$ amount of events. I recall you can: just "range(n), repeat=n" but then have to reconsider "{}{}{}...{}" and "if a!=b and ..." -- basically all a,b,c,...,x must be unique. There was some placeholder for this...

Comment: @hhh check out my updated answer, I think you want adjacent items to be different not all items to be unique.

Comment: Nope, I want all items to be unique. This should simplify the equality check to simple *"if unique(elements)"*.

Comment: @hhh then replace that condition with: `if len(set(p)) == len(p)`

Comment: Yes that is how I have done it in Matlab basically *"if length(unique(p))==length(p)"*, same idea. Thought there would be more elegant way to do it in Python. Yet your code is very elegant! Little thing, thank you.

Comment: @hhh you can also write your own function using sets, keep a track of items seen so far in a `set` and return if the current item is found in set. But for small lists/tuple simply set conversion is going to be fast.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of problems `iterools` is very handy. 
If you want all items to be unique you are looking at permutations:

```
import itertools
[''.join(p) for p in itertools.permutations('012')]
```

['012', '021', '102', '120', '201', '210']

If you want adjacent items to be different:

```
[''.join(p) for p in itertools.product('012', repeat=3) if all(p[i] != p[i+1] for i in range(len(p) - 1))]
```

['010', '012', '020', '021', '101', '102', '120', '121', '201', '202', '210', '212']